# Updating Props (or State) in Inputs Mapped from Object Array with React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, mapping, onchange

I have an object array that I'm outputting to a form of inputs. These inputs need to be updated, the values rendered to show the changes. I'm able to console the key and new value but the error I receive is that `metafields.map` is not a function.

My code is as follows:

```
class EditMetafields extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { metafields: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // retrieving data from the db to populate metafields
    metafields = [
      {id: 0, key: "key0", value: "value0"},
      {id: null, key: "keyNull", value: "valueNull"},
      {id: 2, key: "key2", value: "value2"},
    ]

    this.setState({ metafields: metafields });
  }

  render() {
    const { metafields } = this.state;
    const formFields = metafields.map((props) => 
      <TextField 
        key={props.id} 
        label={props.key} 
        id={prop.id} 
        value={props.value} 
        changeKey={props.id} onChange={(val) =>{
          console.log(props.key, val); //returns accurate output i.e. "key0 value0a" when 'a' key pressed
          this.setState({ metafields: { ...this.state.metafields, [props.key]: val } }) //TypeError: metafields.map is not a function after 'a' key pressed
        }
      } />
    );

    return (
     <Page>
       <Form>
         {formFields}
       </Form>
     </Page>
    )
  }
}
```

When it was an array of object containing a single key/value pair I was able to pair and change without issue but now that I have to attach ids and more to the object React gets upset with `Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I need to work with objects containing id, namespace, key, and value and output each object to a input within a form that can be updated but I'm not sure if I'm using React properly by assigning metafields to props. Links to relevant articles or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian mentioned, this line:

```
this.setState({ metafields: { ...this.state.metafields, [props.key]: val } })
```

changes the `metafields` state variable into an object. What I think you're trying to do, is update an element's value in the `metafields` array, based on key.

To accomplish this, you should use `map` and use the callback variant of `setState` (since you're depending on the previous state of `metafields`):

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return { metafields: prevState.metafields.map(metafield => {
        if (metafield.key === props.key) {
            metafield.value = val;
        }
        return metafield;
    })};
});
```

This code will update the correct element in the `metafields` array with the new value.

Comment: Thank you, I have never used `prevState`, it's going into the toolkit.

Comment: Followup question on this; if I'm seeking to update and element's value in an array without keys would I need only compare the index?